# sliding barn doors offset track

Tags: doors

I would like to make a door system that consists of 2 sliding barn style doors that overlap when open but become flush(as one) when closed.I tought about a normal straight track on one of the doors and a offset (minibus side door) track for the overlapping one.The question is how do I calculate the offset bend angles,lenght and position relative to the closed door so the doors won't grind when opening the offset one.Door dimensions are 2000mmx2200mm(h) in a 4000mm opening.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't achieve what you're after with a simple track bend (there's much more than that to a van door). The overlapping door would have to travel beyond the inline door to get on plane. This would obviously leave a gap. You'll need specialized hardware (or a bevel/rabbet on each slab long enough to accommodate the shift).

Comment: I was thinking of inserting a t track on the inline door with a puller on the offset one.that way the offset door would pass the bend,comming inline and then pull the other door behind,thus becomming flush.bevels are not a problem since I will build my own stuff for the project,it's the bend itself that I don't know how to simulate in order to calculate the rest.

Comment: If you can work that kind of movement buffer into the inline door, there's not much to calculate. Apply the angles you think are appropriate and then apply the necessary extension to the inline door's path so everything clears. (In this type of scenario I tend to work from intuition rather than math and make adjustments as needed--leave a little extra length on your track until the end.)